# httplib 303 See Other responce

Tags: python, django

I'm using httplib to make a post to a server. I'm getting back a 303 See Other. How do I see what the redirect message is '303 See Other' does not really help.

Thanks

```
conn1 = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url, 443, timeout=30)
            headers = {"Content-type": "application/text",
                   "Accept": "2"}

conn1.set_debuglevel(1)
conn1.request("POST", '', body.encode('utf8'), headers)
response = conn1.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Location` header will hold the URL that you are being redirected to:

```
print response.getheader('location')
```

If you want to see the actual page that was sent with the 303 (if there was one), read the response object as usual:

```
contents = response.read()
```